# C++ class Constructor()

Tags: c++, oop, constructor

I have two classes: a class Complex and a class Matrix.

Isn't my constructor supposed to substitute the void arguments constructor as well? It throws an error util I declare Complex() constructor as well. g++ -std=c++14

Complex.h

```
class Complex {

private:
    int m_real, m_imaginary;

public:
    Complex(const int, const int);
}
```

complex.cpp

```
#include "Complex.h"

// Constructor
Complex::Complex(const int real = 0, const int img = 0) : m_real(real), m_imaginary(img) { }
```

Matrix.h

```
class Complex;

class Matrix {

private:
    int m_lines, m_columns;
    Complex *m_matrix;

public:
    Matrix(const int, const int, const Complex &);
}
```

matrix.cpp

```
#include "Matrix.h"
#include "Complex.h"

Matrix::Matrix(const int nr_lines, const int nr_columns, const Complex &comp) : m_lines(nr_lines), m_columns(nr_columns) {
    m_matrix = new Complex[nr_lines * nr_columns];
    some other code goes here...
```

|7|error: no matching function for call to 'Complex::Complex()'|

Comment: Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us? Together with the actual errors you get (in full, complete and unedited)?

Comment: Instead of a raw array, why not use a `std::vector`?

Comment: Please provide more context. And if there is an error copy the text of the error message to your question. If this is Visual Studio the Output tab will have the error in a form that can be copied as text.

Comment: Consider using standard types. `std::vector<std::vector<std::complex<int>>>` should suffice.

Comment: If you don't want to include the definition of Complex then use templates.

Comment: @alexeykuzmin0 Actually they just want `std::vector<std::complex<double>>`.  Just as a `type**` should be avoided for poor cache locality so should a `std::vector<std::vector<type>>`.

Comment: @NathanOliver Agree that `std::vector<std::complex<int>>` is the closest alternative from STL to what is mentioned in the question and agree that such approach will probably have better performance, but `std::vector<std::vector>` has better readability, which usually is more important.

Comment: Maybe he is doing this for a summer course? But generally, yeah, you're usually better of using std types instead of homebrew. @NathanOliver @alexeykuzmin0 I never used std::complex, but he is using `int`. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex states _The effect of instantiating the template `complex` for any other type [than `float`, `double`, `long double`] is unspecified._

Comment: Are you sure that you have default values for `real` and `img` in your code? If there wasn't any default values then `new Complex[n]` would have thrown error without `Complex()`.

Comment: The problem is that you set the constructor default argument values when you *define* the constructor, not when you *declare* it. It needs to be done for the *declaration*.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks, it worked. Didn't know I have to do it in declaration also

Comment: It's *only* needed in the declaration. Remember that source files are really independent from each other (please learn more about [*translation units*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming))) so all the compiler knows is what it sees in the current source file, which is the declaration.

Answer (score 2):

Same here - I tested the code I wrote based on your description.
It compiles and runs just fine on VS2015, VS2017.

```
class Complex
{
private:
   int m_real;
   int m_img;

public:
   Complex(const int real = 0, const int img = 0) 
      : m_real(real)
      , m_img(img)
   {

   }
};

class Matrix
{
private:
   Complex* matrix;

public:
   Matrix(int nr_lines = 3, int nr_columns = 3)
   {
      matrix = new Complex[nr_lines * nr_columns];
   }

   ~Matrix()
   {
      delete[] matrix;
   }
};

int main()
{
   Matrix* t = new Matrix();
   return 1;
}
```

Comment: Your problem is in the declaration of the Complex constructor, in complex.h file. There, you didn't declare the default values. Copy the signature of the constructor from complex.cpp, and it should work

Answer (score 1):

It seems your error is somewhere else.
As *Some programmer dude* pointed out, you could have figured this out with a minimal, complete and verifiable example - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

I created a small example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

class Complex {
    private:
        int m_n;
        int m_i;

    public:
        Complex (const int n = 0, const int i = 0) : m_n (n), m_i (i) {
            std::cout << "Complex ctor: " << n << ", " << i << std::endl;
        };
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int cnt = 12;
    if (argc > 1)
        cnt = atoi (argv[1]);
    Complex* m = new Complex[cnt];
    (void)m; //no warning for unused variable
    return 0;
}
```

Building with g++ and running:

```
pan:~$ g++ example.cpp -Wall -o example.elf
pan:~$ ./example.elf 4
Complex ctor: 0, 0
Complex ctor: 0, 0
Complex ctor: 0, 0
Complex ctor: 0, 0
pan:~$
```

As you can see, **this C++ class constructor works well & as expected**.

My gcc is *g++ (SUSE Linux) 4.8.5*.